# Time Comparison in VBA evaluating False

Tags: excel, vba

I have Date/Times stored in two variables enDate and stDate - they are shift times which at most are 10 hours apart. I want to test if the stDate is after 9pm and if the enDate is before 7am.

My attempt is :

```
Sub Test()

Dim startDate As String, endDate As String
Dim stDate As Date
Dim enDate As Date

startDate = "2021-10-06 22:00:00.000"
endDate = "2021-10-07 07:00:00.000"

stDate = CDate(Left(startDate, Len(startDate) - 4))
enDate = CDate(Left(endDate, Len(endDate) - 4))

If TimeValue(stDate) > TimeValue("20:59:00") And TimeValue("03:00:00") < TimeValue(enDate) Then
```

[image]

The problem is that `TimeValue("03:00:00") < TimeValue(enDate)` evaluates to False even though 03:00 is less than 07:00. Why?

Comment: With your code `TimeValue("03:00:00") < TimeValue(enDate)` evaluates to TRUE on my computer.  `Debug.Print TimeValue(stDate) > TimeValue("20:59:00") And TimeValue("03:00:00") < TimeValue(enDate)` also returns TRUE.

Comment: Your watch is using "Less Than."  7:00 < 3:00, is False

Comment: Your Watch window is showing False as it's  `TimeValue(enDate) < TimeValue("03:00:00")` - a time value of 7am isn't less than 3am